# How can i place an element in an array on a given position?

Tags: java, arrays, addition, element

I have the following question.

```
int[] ar={4,6,7,8}
```

Now i want to add an element so i get

```
ar={4,6,9,7,8}
```

I want to be able to add a given element (9) in a position that i want i this case index 2. How?

Comment: An array's length is **final**. Which means if you want to add or remove elements, you need to create a new array and copy everything along with new element.

Comment: Ok, so there is no simple method. i have to use Arraylist.But then how to convert my ar to an arrylist.?

Comment: there are API's existing to convert array's to list. Like `Arrays.asList()`, but they will give **fixed sized list** which means you cant add or remove from them as well. So you need to copy the list to a new one with `new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(arr))`. Or you could use [`System.arrayCopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) and copy from original array to your new array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, the size of an array cannot be changed. Instead you can use a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html):

```
List<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
numList.add(4);
numList.add(6);
numList.add(7);
numList.add(8);
```

Then you can use `numList.add(int index, E element);` to insert values at specific positions.

```
numList.add(2, 9);
//numList = {4, 6, 9, 7, 8};
```

For further information you may want to look at [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html).

Comment: Use a `List` and... then do what? (You should perhaps say to use `List.insert`).

Comment: @AndyTurner I added links to the Javadoc and an Oracle tutorial.

Comment: @Turing85 but you've not mentioned what to look for in the javadoc or tutorial. It would be a better answer to say explicitly that `List.insert` is the pertinent method.

Comment: exactly, just giving a tutorial dont cut it. Those are big and i dont know where to look for :-( still thx.

Comment: @mr_ecko there is a subsection called "The List Interface", which explains the most basic stuff about `List`s. Who am I to decide what is "important"  to you and what is not? Therefore I like to give more general information and let you decide what to pick. The subpage is maybe five printed pages long.

Answer (score 0):

Java arrays are fixed length, so you'll need to create another one to store your extra element.

```
int[] ar = { 4, 6, 7, 8 };
int[] tmp = new int[ar.length + 1];
int pos = 2;
for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
    tmp[i] = ar[i];
}
for (int i = pos + 1; i <= ar.length; i++) {
    tmp[i] = ar[i - 1];
}
tmp[pos] = 9;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tmp));
```

Output is (as requested)

```
[4, 6, 9, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Just for documentation: when you ever need to copy arrays within productive code, please use [`System.arraycopy(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) (I am pretty sure Elliott Frisch knows this).

Answer (score 0):

[How to add new elements to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843366/how-to-add-new-elements-to-an-array)

[add an element to int [] array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899699/add-an-element-to-int-array-in-java)

Note that ArrayList also has an add method that lets you specify an index and the element to be added `void add(int index, E element)`.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way of doing this is to use an `ArrayList<Integer>` and use the `add(int, T)` method.

```
List<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
numList.add(4);
numList.add(6);

// Now, we will insert the number
numList.add(2, 9);
```