# Append function In Java?

Tags: java, python, arrays, list

I am trying to append an item to the empty list which I created in java by using

```
String[] list_of_days = {};
```

How can I append the items, e.g., numbers from 1 to 10, in this list, like I used to do in Python using append function.

```
list_of_numbers.append(variable)??`enter code here`
```

Comment: Arrays are fixed-size. Use a `List`

Comment: That's an array, it's not resizable. You want a `List<String>` instead.

Comment: If you know the array size from the beginning, then https://stackoverflow.com/a/36438433/4852017 seems very useful. If not, then an ArrayList<String> might be more helpful as you can just call arrList.add()

Comment: It should be better to use StringBuilder class and append the values